# Relevant data structure

Tags: data-structures, key-value

I have 5 million key-value pairs. Kindly suggest a relevant data structure for storing such a huge data. What if my data can expand to 1 billion key-value pairs in future? Kindly suggest a data structure in Java which will accommodate this data.

Comment: you have probably researched on the subject before asking, what will be your first choices? have you tried some initial attempt? what problems did you find?

Comment: Yes.. i tried to insert 5 million Integer-Integer key-value pairs into HashMap and HashTable both. Also, i retrieved value at key 1 million. I could see that insertion in HashMap took 7145 milliseconds whereas HashTable took 7849 milliseconds. Performance of both data structures is not acceptable i feel.

Comment: Later, i tried to insert 1 billion records and found that my program threw exception "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space". Can this problem be solved using Trove library?

Comment: Why are those values unacceptable?  Also what is the hash function you are using?  There is a good chance that it is a poor hash.

Comment: If you feel that performance is unacceptable, then what would acceptable performance be?  It is easier to know when to quit if the goal is, "I need it under five seconds." than to know when to quit if the goal is "can it be made any faster?"

Comment: I got your point Edwin. I was just concerned about 7 seconds for insertion. Moreover, point mentioned by Woot4Moo is good i have to chunk the data and can use TreeMap for storing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use a [TreeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) .  To answer the question about doing this in memory, it cannot all be in memory at once (at least with todays standard technology on a desktop in 2011) you want to chunk in the data.  Since the information is already sorted with a tree map you can effectively determine, using binary sort or one of its variants, where in the tree it falls.  Trove will not fix an out of memory exception, that has to do with the JVM settings.

Answer (score 4):

**[Hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)** support one of the most efficient types of searching.

Comment: +1 hashtables provide O(1) lookups, assuming a decent hash function

Answer (score 1):

Any data structure *can* store a lot of information, but to know which one you need to use you have to consider how the information is going to be added, removed, and accessed.  You may also have to consider whether the information needs to remain in memory, or if it is acceptable to only have the most recently / most frequently used parts of the data in memory.

Key value pairs imply `Map`s, which are generally collections of Key-Value pairs.  However, there are many ways to implement a `Map`, from a simple array (requires consecutive keys, all integers) to B-Trees of keys with associated references to their values.

Without knowing what the running characteristics should be for the program, it is not possible to know if an algorithm or data structure is "good enough" for the data set size.

Full listings in alphabetical order, an ordered list of Key-Value pairs is fastest.  Searching with the full key available, a HashMap (or hash based algorithm) will serve you well.  Searching with a pattern that can partially match keys, perhaps a Tree of Keys ordered to facilitate the search would be better.  In short, it depends on how the data is going to be used, in addition to the expected size of the data set.

Answer (score 0):

All this data, needs to be in memory? If the answer is no, you could use a database and index your data by the key.

If the answer to the above question is yes: what kind of objects are you planning to store? can they be represented as primitive data types? I'd suggest that you take a look at the high-speed collections implemented in the [Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com) library.

Comment: I need to store objects such as 'Student with rollno, name as instance variables'. thanks for the input. I will explore trove now.